# TypeError when trying to use pydig program

Tags: python, dns

I am trying to run this python program https://github.com/shuque/pydig.
When I try to run the pydig.py file with `python pydig www.example.com` I get an error message saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pydig", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
    File "C:\Users\User\desktop\pydig-master\pydiglib\main.py", line 20, in main qname, qtype, qclass = parse_args(args[1:])
    File "C:\Users\User\desktop\pydig-master\pydiglib\options.py", line 206, in parse_args options["server"] = get_default_server()
    File "C:\Users\User\desktop\pydig-master\pydiglib\util.py", line 156, in get_default_server s = get_windows_default_dns()
    File "C:\Users\User\desktop\pydig-master\pydiglib\windows.py", line 7, in get_windows_default_dns match_obj = re_ipv4.search(output)
    TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Can someone tell me what's the problem? I am using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i kinda solved it by returning a fixed server IP.
But i couldn't get it to work by decoding the byte to stream to a string.